# Signing out with Devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Im having problems with signing out with devise, i get the following error message when i try to sign out, its looking for a user with the id=sign_out. Any suggestions?

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with id=sign_out
```

Routes

```
  devise_for :users

  match 'users/settings',  to: 'users#settings'

  resources :users, only: [:show, :update]
```

Link

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Rake Routes

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                           devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#destroy
          users_settings        /users/settings(.:format)                         users#settings
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: have you resolved this? Having the exact same issue with rails 4

Comment: Im sorry had a look at the my old code but couldn't figure out what i had to change for it to work. All i can remember is i changed the order in which i had devise_for :users and match 'users/settings', to: 'users#settings' in my routes file :(

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've solved this problem, You need try to put or check the below line in your views/layouts/application.html.erb

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Also check if you have jquery_ujs in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually clicking on the correct link. I highly doubt that link routes the request to `UsersController#show`. `destroy_user_session_path` routes to `/users/sign_out` so this is impossible.

Comment: I looked at the terminal which started a get request, so i changed the config.sign_out_via = :delete to :get and now it works.... :/